# Past perfect tense and Since

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect

> Lenny had slept most of the way since leaving Texas.

I found this sentence from Cambridge Dictionary. I have been taught that you use past perfect tense to emphasize an event in the past that took place before another past event, and you also need to use past simple on the event or action that took place afterward to form a complete sentence.

The quoted sentence seems to violate these rules. In this sentence, *leaving Texas* happened before *had slept*, and there's no past simple to be found. Is this sentence grammatical in the first place? Is there a name for this particular sentence structure?

Comment: We would expect a sentence like this to be part of a longer story. The rule you were taught doesn't have to apply to a single sentence. The narrative could continue _However, he woke and began to look about him when they reached [place name]._

Comment: @KateBunting Is it possible that the next sentence doesn't provide any information that is related to the quoted sentence?

Comment: I was explaining to you the _most likely reason_ for using that tense.